# SSMS version 18 – no Database Diagrams

Tags: sql-server, ssms, ssms-18

I notice that Database Diagrams are not supported in SSMS version 18, any idea why, and is there a way to get the same functionality?

And why is the T-SQL debugger gone now?

Answer (score 43):

As it was posted at June 11, 2019, to announce that **[SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.1 is now generally available](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/06/11/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-1-is-now-generally-available/)**, the Database diagrams is back in [SSMS 18.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-and-removed-features-in-180-ga) along side  SSBDIAGNOSE.EXE and Integration Services (SSIS)

---

Original Answer:

The feature is deprecated, you can visit [SQL Server Management Studio - Changelog (SSMS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) page and read the *[Deprecated Features](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#deprecated-and-removed-features-in-180-ga)* in SSMS 18.0.

> #### Deprecated Features
>
> The following features are no longer available in SSMS:
>
> - T-SQL Debugger
> - Database Diagrams
> - …

Those features are available in earlier versions, you can use one of them a long side with SSMS 18.0

Comment: Currently, [as described here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37507828), any diagrams created with V18 will not open again once SSMS is closed. Older diagrams are good.

Answer (score 24):

SQL Server Management Studio 18.1 was just released on June 11th, and it supports Database Diagrams again.

According to this blogpost [SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 18.1 is now generally available](https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2019/06/11/sql-server-management-studio-ssms-18-1-is-now-generally-available/):

> Yes, we’ve heard the feedback; Database Diagrams is back.

Here's the [SSMS download page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017).

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem with SSMS 18 (preview 4)

To get the functionality, install a previous SSMS release until the fix comes.

[Download SSMS 17.8.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/sql-server-management-studio-changelog-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#downloadssdtmediadownloadpng-ssms-1781httpsgomicrosoftcomfwlinklinkid875802)

Comment: FYI Be sure to uninstall the newer one before installing the previous. They do not work side by side.

Comment: @ΩmegaMan Actually separate versions of SSMS (17, 18, etc) do work side-by-side, as always.

Comment: Understood, at the time it failed for me; maybe it was installed in the same directory (?). Regardless disregard my comment.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Complete](https://blog.devart.com/start-debugging-within-ssms-with-the-help-of-sql-complete-6-4.html) now has T-SQL debugger feature for SSMS v18.